# Migrate TFS 2008 source code to TFS 2010

Tags: version-control, tfs, tfs-migration

I want to migrate all the source code from a TFS 2008 server to a new installation of TFS 2010. There are no work items, reports or portal to migrate, only source code. We want to move to a new process template and don't want to make an upgrade of the template used in TFS 2008 projects. Are there any good tools to only migrate source code? I've done some tests with `TimelyMigrations` `TfsToTfs` but they don't seem to work well when migrating a lot of source code.

Has anyone tried to use Team Foundation Server Integration Tool? I suppose you need to upgrade the TFS 2008 to TFS 2010 before you are able to move the source code to a new TPC/TP with the process template we want to use (with fresh portal and reports). Is this correct?

Comment: Is there a reason you can't do an in place upgrade to TFS 2010?

Comment: I realise this is an old question, but from what you've said, can't you simply check the code out in TFS 2008 and in in TFS 2010?